# Where does Monodevelop Git Extension on Windows look for SSH keys?

Tags: git, monodevelop

I'm running Monodevelop on Windows. I've install Git Extensions (which includes msysGit). I used mysysGit to generate an RSA key pair (ssh-keygen -t rsa), and added that key to our Git server (using Gitlab). That set up is correct: I can push and pull using the command line, as well as the Git Extensions GUI (which itself uses the command line). In Monodevelop, however, push and pull fail.

Version Control > Update causes Monodevelop to prompt me for the git user password. This is the behavior I'd also see in the command line if I hadn't put my public key in Gitlab. So it looks like Monodevelop is looking for my SSH key in some other location; I have it stored in C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa.pub .

So, where does Monodevelop Git expect to find the key? This is working for a colleague of mine, but I can't figure out why we're seeing different behavior.

This Monodevelop 3.0.3.4, and Git support 3.0.3. Both are the latest versions available as far as I know.

Comment: keep to the command line. What does git extensions give you that you don't get with MSysGit?

Comment: I actually prefer the command line, but some developers on the team are more comfortable with GUI tools, so I'm looking into options.

Git Extensions includes msysGit, and also adds a GUI and some (somewhat kludgy) integration with Visual Studio.

Comment: command history in itself is valuable enough to give them a reason to change their minds. Preference is not good enough when you can't remember how you got yourself into a situation.

Comment: I agree, and suspect they will change their minds after they've gotten used to Git. However, I am trying to ease the transition from TFS, so I'm checking what the GUI options are.

Comment: ugh.. tfs.. good that you're getting rid of that. Show them Git Gui and Gitk. You can do almost everything in those 2.

Answer (score 1):

When installing Git from git-scm.com, one of the dialogs during the installation asks you to pick an option about how much you want to modify the environment. It presents three options, where option 1 is default and is described as safe. **I had to pick the unsafe option 3 in order to make it work.** It may, however, be sufficient to set some environment variable in Windows, but I could not figure out which one that would be.